# Cross-compiling on freebsd13.1 with freebsd11.4

Tags: cross-compiling, freebsd

im trying to compile the freebsd11.4 32x on my freebsd13.1 x64 root and I got an issue where I cant find any fix for it.

What I did so far for the compiling:

```
wget https://archive.freebsd.org/old-releases/i386/11.4-RELEASE/src.txz

tar -C / -xvzf src.txz

mkdir /usr/x86/

cd /usr/src
make TARGET_ARCH=i386 buildworld
```

My error:

```
rm -f .depend .depend.* GPATH GRTAGS GSYMS GTAGS
===> lib/libarchive (cleandir)
===> lib/libarchive/tests (cleandir)
make[5]: "/usr/src/lib/libarchive/tests/../Makefile.inc" line 11: Malformed conditional (${MK_OPENSSL} != "no")
make[5]: "/usr/src/lib/libarchive/tests/../Makefile.inc" line 18: Malformed conditional (${MK_ICONV} != "no")
make[5]: "/usr/src/share/mk/src.libnames.mk" line 570: /usr/src/lib/libarchive/tests: Invalid LIBADD used which may need to be added to src.l               ibnames.mk: zstd

make[5]: stopped in /usr/src/lib/libarchive/tests
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[4]: stopped in /usr/src/lib/libarchive
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[3]: stopped in /usr/src/lib
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[2]: stopped in /usr/src
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/src
*** Error code 1
```

Maybe someone could help me out :)

Comment: You probably just can't do that. Try building 11.4 in a 11.4 jail.

Comment: Your `tar -C / -xvzf src.txz` has overiden your 13.1 src tree. (ie any updates has been lost.). `chroot`, `jail` and `bhyve` could provide some help. Some doc here [Cross Compiling FreeBSD for Fun and Profit](https://wiki.freebsd.org/WarnerLosh/A_Brief_Guide_To_Cross_Compiling_FreeBSD) and here [ARM Cross build](https://wiki.freebsd.org/arm/crossbuild). And yes, you can do that. Just read the doc.

Comment: You can probably get around this failure by specifying "WITHOUT_TESTS" in src.conf but most likely run into other errors.